# Set background-color on not only the text and also empty space in a td

Tags: css

I want to set the background color to hole td using span.

Here is my code:

```
<td>
<span style="background-color: red;">pending</span>
</td>
```

If I give it like this I am getting background color to text only but i want bg color to hole td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <td>
        <span style="background-color: red;width:100%;height:100%;display:block;">pending</span>
    </td>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NFsup/)

Comment: Can you add more html code and css styles to your post? Because my code works (you can see it on the link "example")

Answer (score 3):

```
<td style="background-color: red;">
<span>pending</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi ubercooluk,, i dont want to use styles in td.. so using span it should set the bg color..any other alternatives

Comment: or give a class to your td say `.foo` and add styles in ur css

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td>
    <span style="background-color: red; display:block;">
           pending
        </span>
      </td> 
   </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color on the cell itself not the span

Comment: ok so set the spans width and height to 100% that should fill the parent (in this case the td)